# I think my using directive creates .dll i don't want to have

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2017

My Project map has 3 projects. I don't have many references and there shouldn't be many .dll files. 
But in my Release folder are over 100!!! .dll files.

[Here you see some .dll files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilwVf.png)

.dll files like System.IO i never had and i wonder where it comes from. I see no references and nothing.

My only idea is, that the dll files are created because of the using directive 
using System.IO and other stuff.

Do you know why i have so many dll files?

My team is pretty confused and our only idea is to create the project again from scratch because we can't get rid of these .dll files.

Comment: Why you use `using`s if you don't use them? That sounds like you have used them some time and then removed that code. Remove the dll's(and redundant usings) if they are not necessary. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/7314433t(v=vs.90)

Comment: i mean, i need the using s and i use them. But never before there were .dll files created.
also if i remove the dll files manually, the next build creates them again.
my usings:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceProcess;

Comment: Because the project references have set `copy local` to `true`(right click the dll in visual studio). You don't need to deploy them if they are contained in the GAC of the target computer.

Comment: i thought about it, too. 
i have only 2 project references set to "true". a project  with only 1 class (it is a setting.xml for both projects) and itextsharp is set to true, too.
The rest like System is set on false :/

Answer (score 2):

> But never before there were .dll files created. also if i remove the
>   dll files manually, the next build creates them again

Because the project references have set `copy local` to `true`(click the dll in visual studio). You don't need to deploy them if they are contained in the GAC of the target computer. You can check in the visual studio developer console if a dll is contained in the GAC with:

```
gacutil /l System.IO
```

Comment: i thought about it, too. i have only 2 project references set to "true". a project with only 1 class (it is a setting.xml for both projects) and itextsharp is set to true, too. The rest like System is set on false :/

Comment: @nninja: you need to rebuild in debug/release mode to remove them. Try to switch to true and then back to false and then rebuild the solution.

Comment: mhmm :/
I just did rebuild each time after i set all the references local copy to true and then to false. 
Even when it is false -> all the dlls are still created :o

Then maybe it s something else :/ or some kind of weird bug...

Comment: Someone gave me the hint, it is maybe because i use a .NETCore reference. and i use one. probably thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did a beginners mistake :)

I wanted to create a normal class library but somehow i clicked on the .NETCore library and worked for days without knewing it was a .netcore library.

Deleting the .NetCore library and replacing with a normal one and fixing all the reference errors solved the problem

Comment: Even with "normal" projects, if you use anything for the .NET Standard eco-system, you'll see a lot of packages pulled in for stuff that's already in the framework. That's the "price" we pay for .NET Standard being common between Framework and Core (and really, the extra references aren't generally a *problem*)